# Using VBA to attach a file in an outlook email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've created a subroutine that grabs all the relevant details and attachments to send out automated emails for me. Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim To1 As String, CC1 As String, BCC1 As String, Title1 As String, Body1 As String, Att1 As String


' Create "Other Distribution - In Email" Emails

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
To1 = Cells(8, 2).Value
CC1 = Cells(8, 3).Value
BCC1 = Cells(8, 4).Value
Title1 = Cells(8, 5).Value
Body1 = Cells(8, 6).Value
Att1 = Cells(8, 7).Value

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        ' BodyFormat command makes the email a rich format message allowing us to place attachments within the body of the email instead of in the attachment header
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .To = To1
        .CC = CC1
        .BCC = BCC1
        .Subject = Title1
        .Body = Body1
        .Attachments.Add Att1, , 10
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works fine and inserts my attachment at the end of my email body. The issue is this specific line:

```
.Attachments.Add Att1, , 10
```

In this code the "10" is supposed to represent the position of the attachment. I.E. this is supposed to mean that after the first 9 characters in my "Body1" variable, instead of the 10th character the attachment will be placed here. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx

However, for some reason no matter what number I put in the position option it always just puts my attachment at the very end of the email. I need the attachment to be in the middle of several paragraphs so this is causing an issue. Any idea what is causing this?

I should mention I have selected the Microsoft Outlook Object Library from Tools>References.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that this is a bug in Outlook 2008/2010 for which there does not seem to be a fix :(

http://argurosblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-create-task-or-appointment-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of the body with:

```
    Body1 = "This is the body of the mail, line 1" & vbcrlf 
    Body1 = Body1 &  "This is the second line of text, line 2" & vbcrlf 
    Body1 = Body1 & "This is the last line of text, line 3."
```

and run your code.

As you can see the attachment is not placed after the 10.th character, but after the first `vbcrlf` found after the 10.th character.

If you try with `.Attachments.Add Att1, , 50` (in the middle of the second line), it will be placed between line 2 and line 3.

If you delete all the `vbcrlf`s characters in your body, it will placed at the end of the body, and that is probably what happens to you.

Parse the content of your body and insert `vbcrlf` ('hard returns') characters where needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This doesn't seem to be working. It's still dropping the attachment at the end of the email for some reason. I tried playing around with the position parameter and tried #'s 1-3, 35-40, 50, and 100. All of them dropped by attachment at the very end of the email...

Comment: @YASPLS What version of Outlook are you using? This was tested with Outlook2013 and runs as described.

Comment: Cisco, thanks for trying to help. See my other post bellow. I'm using Outlook 2010 and apparently this is a known bug with no fixes.